# Determine odds for a series of rolls of dice

Tags: probability, dice

If you have one die, lets say in 6 continuous rolls you roll the following:

3....3....6......2.....1....4

What is the possibility that after you roll the next 3....

That the following rolls would be.....

3......6......2......1......4.     In that exact order for the following 5 rolls?

I don't think thus is too difficult a question but I don't have the knowledge to answer it.

Comment: What is the probability that the next roll is $3?$  That the next two rolls are $3,6$ in that order?  And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Each roll takes a value from the set $\{1,2,\;...,6\}$, independent of past or future rolls. So the probability of seeing any sequence of 5 rolls is $\left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^5$, regardless of what the sequence might be.